# Is there a way to make a reference of positional parameter in bash?

Tags: bash

I would like to make my bash script more easy to read.
To do so, I would like to make a reference of positional parameters to name them.

I tried

```
declare -n time="\$1"
```

But it did not work. I got error message,

```
declare: $1: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "$1")
```

Someone who has solutions or suggestions, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Namerefs make it easy to modify a variable indirectly. Positional parameters, however, are essentially read-only, in the sense that you can't assign directly to them. (You use `set` to update the positional parameters as a whole, rather than updating any one individually.)

If you just want a better name for a positional parameter, just use regular parameter assignment.

```
time=$1
```

(Formally, there are three distinct kinds of parameters in shell:

1. Positional parameters: `$1`, `$2`, etc
2. Special parameters: `$?`, `$*`, etc (single-character, non-alphanumeric names)
3. Variables:  "regular" parameters with a valid identifier for a name

`declare -n` is used to create references to variables only.
)

Comment: Thank you, chepner. Let me ask you one more question. I wonder whether I should quote the positional parameter, like time="$1", or not.

Comment: There's no harm, but if the parameter is by itself on the RHS, it isn't necessary. The two big reasons for quoting a parameter expansion (to prevent word-splitting and pathname expansion) do not occur in assignments.

Comment: IMO, it's best to just get in the habit of double-quoting variable references in the shell. It isn't necessary in this case (and a few others), but understanding and keeping track of when it's safe and when it isn't is harder than you might think... so I'd just go ahead and double-quote it.

Comment: Thank you, chepner and Gordon Davisson. On the basis of your instruction, I will double quote positional parameters even at assignment. It seems I can stay safer more easily.